# 18TB with ext4 filesystem

Tags: ext4

I have the server with 4 disks 6TB each. At start disks were configured as RAID 10 and I had 11TB partition with ex4 filesystem on it. I grew up RAID from level 10 to 5 and now it’s 17.9TB. After reconfiguring RAID I used resize2fs for resize partition, but with ext4 32 bit it give me only 16TB available space. How can I use more than 16TB?

This is parted print information:

```
GNU Parted 3.2

Using /dev/md3

Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.

(parted) p

Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)

Disk /dev/md3: 17.9TB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B

Partition Table: loop

Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags

1      0.00B  17.9TB  17.9TB  ext4
```

This is available space:

```
df -h

Filesystem      Size

/dev/md3         16T
```

Maybe I can create second partition?

Thanks.

Comment: try to use future auto_64-bit_support = 1 in /etc/mke2fs.conf

Comment: Don’t use RAID5. It’s obsolete.

Comment: I really second what Sven said. Unrecoverable read errors are a matter of statistic. With 100 GB drives, you don't run into this. With today's disks, you're almost guaranteed to have at least one on a full disk read. With RAID5, that means a high probability of failure on rebuild.

Comment: What Sven says - PLEASE don't use R5, it's staggeringly dangerous, especially with big/slow disks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a limitation of x32 ext4. Check this [link](https://www.unix-ninja.com/p/Formatting_Ext4_volumes_beyond_the_16TB_limit) as a possible workaround. Don't use RAID-5 for spindle drives especially for 6TB drives. Just imagine the time of rebuilding the RAID array in case if your disk will fail and very poor write performance.

Comment: Unfortunayely I can't convert ext4 to 64 bit, because of server run with Debian Jessie 3.16 kernel. Is it possible to use space another way, like second volume maybe? How can I create a second volume in this situation?